# Custom UIFont SwiftUI & Xcode 14.1

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode14

First I am aware of the fact that questions like this have been asked before but having reviewed all of the answers I am still having issues.

I am writing my first project in SwiftUI using Xcode 14.1 and wanted to add a custom font. I first created a `Fonts` group within the project and added the .ttf files to the project using `Add Files to "Project"` ensuring that `Copy items if needed` was checked.

I then went and added the `Fonts provided by application` to the `Custom iOS Target Properties` and the array items for the font in this case `Poppins` so the values read `Fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf`

```
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Fonts/Poppins-Black.ttf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Poppins-BlackItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Poppins-BoldItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Poppins-ExtraBold.ttf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Poppins-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Poppins-ExtraLight.ttf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Poppins-ExtraLightItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Poppins-Italic.ttf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Poppins-LightItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Poppins-MediumItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Poppins-SemiBoldItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Poppins-Thin.ttf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Poppins-ThinItalic.ttf</string>
    </array>
```

However, when printing out my fonts in an `init()` method that calls this function within my `App` swift file:

```
    func printFonts() {
        let fontFamilyNames = UIFont.familyNames
        
        for familyName in fontFamilyNames {
            print("----------")
            print("Font Family Name -> [\(familyName)]")
            let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName)
            print("Font Names ==> [\(names)]")
        }
    }
```

It Doesn't output my custom font, equally when using the font in my view it doesn't render:

```
Text("Hello!")
    .font(Font.custom("Poppins-Regular", size: 18))
```

Interestingly the preview in Xcode doesn't work since adding this property to the Text in the view reporting the following error: `Compiling failed: ambiguous use of 'font'`

I have searched and searched and try a number of rabbit hole solutions can any one advise?

Comment: You don't need to include the group name in the font array, so just `<string>Poppins-Black.ttf</string>`

Comment: @AshleyMills - I think that may have worked can you submit it as an answer and I will mark it as the accepted resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to include the group name in the font array, so just e.g.

```
<string>Poppins-Black.ttf</string>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it's always the simple things!